# React.JS POST value with XMLHttpRequest in windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I'm just trying to store some value using rest API.

```
[{"userID":1,"passwordHash":"asdasd","email":"admin@admin.com"},{"userID":2,"passwordHash":"12345","email":"admin@admin.com"}]
```

This is what my data looks like.

I'm using Spring boot on the server side on windows machine. To post value I'm using this in the console :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"aszzzzzzzzzzd\", \"passwordHash\": \"sad\" }" http://localhost:8080/user
```

Now I'm trying to `POST` from my react.js application. So I'm using `XMLHttpRequest()`

Here is the code on my react.js application :

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/user');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ email: this.state.email,passwordHash:this.state.password }));
```

I've added `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` to receive requests from my app.

But the problem is, it gives me an error saying :

**POST http://localhost:8080/user 415**

[image: react.js http request]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request header wasn't formatted properly and needed to send information as a value:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```